# Nginx missing trailing slash returns 301

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have the following config:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;

  location  /app {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.html?$args;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

When navigating to `http://localhost:8000/app/` all works as expected but when removing the trailing slash (`http://localhost:8000/app`) nginx returns 301 status response and I am being redirected to `http://localhost/app`.

How can I make nginx work with both `http://localhost:8000/app/` and `http://localhost:8000/app` (with and without trailing slash).

Comment: What do you want `nginx` to do when a URI without a trailing `/` points to a directory? At the moment `$uri/` tells it to issue a `3xx` response, and the `listen` directive tells it to use port 80 in the redirect.

Comment: @RichardSmith  I want both http://localhost:8000/app/ and http://localhost:8000/app point to the same place (the index.html)

Comment: The redirect is caused by `$uri/` in the `try_files` statement. You could just remove it.

Comment: @RichardSmith, are you suggesting putting only `try_files $uri /app/index.html?$args;`? can you post it as an answer - for it to be excepted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `$uri/` term in the `try_files` statement causes `nginx` to append a trailing `/` to the requested URI, if that URI resolves to a local directory. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

The trailing `/` is appended by issuing a 3xx response, and of course `nginx` gets the port wrong as it knows nothing about port 8000.

If you do not want `nginx` to issue any 3xx responses, simply remove the `$uri/` term from your `try_files` statement.

For example:

```
location  /app {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri /app/index.html?$args;
}
```

Comment: It didn't help. I am still being redirected to `http://localhost/app/` after going to `http://localhost:8000/app` - still `http://localhost:8000/app/` works as expected

Comment: Did you restart nginx, and did you clear the browser cache?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this:

```
 port_in_redirect on;
```

But watch out for forward ports if you want your server to be public.