# Nginx try_files works werid with alias

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to fixing [Nginx missing trailing slash returns 301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668879/nginx-missing-trailing-slash-returns-301), so I make a simple demo below.

```
location /download {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri /download.html;
}
500 Internal Server Error
[error] 17224#11648: *12 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/download.html", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /download HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

So I changed the nginx config, found below configs works fine:

```
location /download {
        alias html;
        try_files $uri /download.html =404;
}

location /download {
        root html;
        try_files $uri /download.html;
}

location /download {
        alias html;
        try_files /download.html $uri;
}
```

I'm quite confused about the difference.

Comment: Your first `location` block aliases the URI `/download.html` to `/usr/share/nginx/html.html` which presumably is the wrong pathname, and results in a loop. But I would avoid using `alias` and `try_files` together in the same block due to [this long term issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).

Comment: @RichardSmith But the error log said that redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/download.html" not html.html. It's strange when I swap $uri and /download.html, it work fine.

Comment: The URI is `/download.html` which you have aliased to the pathname ending with `html.html`.  The error message is reporting the URI.